# Generate PHP code from WSDL (for service replacement)

Tags: php, wsdl, code-generation, yii, wsdl2code

We have few Web Services witch now are handled by an external application, and we plan to replace them as an new own implementation.

Is there some tool/class witch will generate stock php interface and structures 100% compatible with those WSDL's we have now?

I'll have to re-implement this wsdl interface, and i have to be sure, that interface itself (not a logic implementation), will not change in any way (even WSDL location have to stay as is)

I have found some projects like: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2php-interpreter

If any of You have used some things like that, please share with me tips, tools recommendations etc.

PS
re-implementation will be made on top of Yii framework and CWebService class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2php-interpreter and based on generated code wrote an web service controllers following a Yii giude and everything works fine and as expected :)

Answer (score 2):

wsdl2php-interpreter is limited -- it doesn't handle attributes and doesn't seem to handle simpleTypes.

Comment: Then try WsdlToPhp ;)